# Selenium clickMethods unification

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm using a 3.11 Selenium Webdriver with PageObject pattern in my automation tests, but recently I noticed there is a lot of duplication code with simple click methods, for example:

```
@Getter
public class ExamplePage extends PageObject {

@FindBy(xpath ="somePath")
private WebElement firstElement;

@FindBy(xpath ="somePath")
private WebElement secondElement;

@FindBy(xpath ="somePath")
private WebElement thirdElement;

(...)

public ExamplePage (WebDriver driver) {
super(driver);
}

public void clickFirst(){
this.firstElement.click();
}

public void clickSecond(){
this.secondElement.click();
}

public void clickThird(){
this.thirdElement.click();
}
(...)
}
```

This approach violates DRY rule and I'm pretty sure there is a better solution. Could you please give me some advice about it?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that there is no need to have a separate method for clicking each element. It might even save more space in your ExamplePage class. So whenever you need to click an element e.g. as part of a bigger method/workflow, you can simply call `firstElement.click()` which is not particularly different from `clickFirst()` apart from the fact that you are saving more space by not having to create click methods in the former.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's really helpful, but it seems to be a workaround instead of a solution.

Comment: You're welcome. You can think of it from the perspective of when you need to create a method and when you don't. For example if the clickFirst() method involved 5 lines of code, then it will definitely be worth it because you don't want to create 5 lines of code whenever you want to click. These are the kind of general considerations to review before creating methods.

Comment: Yes, sure that you are right, but I'm looking rather some type of generic mechanism, best solution for me would be some sort of spring- based aspect annotation

Comment: what u can do is create a base class for all the generic methods, pass the driver instance to it, and lets say the method looks like this

public void clickElement(WebElement element) {
    element.click();
}

and call this method from your page class, this way you are saving lot many lines + using the generic method for actions. You can moreover customize this generic method depending on ur needs.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is kind of half-way in between the other two answers I see here.

First, there's nothing wrong with having a click method for your page object web elements, at least the ones that will potentially be clicked.

Second, one of the main ideas of using a page object model to begin with is to separate the page object from the test logic, including (in my opinion at least) the Selenium code, including click, sendKeys, getText, etc.

Third, I take it one step further and write a set of Selenium wrapper functions that the page object model calls for these functions and passes the web elements and optionally a textual description of the object for logging/error purposes.  This way, I can thoroughly check for the presence of the web element, the visibility of the element, whether or not it's enabled, etc. in one central method that gets called by the page object model elements.  This allows for a robust method that takes into account as many scenarios as necessary to be able to do proper testing, reporting, and error handling.

The page object model still generally has one line of code for these simpler, non-specific methods, but they are all handled the same way without having to write additional code for each click, either in the page object model or (gasp) the test script itself.

You can't get around coding clicks - it's just a matter of -where- you put them, and how robust the code is that actually does the click, and how centrally located those methods are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it. You are completely right about the main PageObject idea to split up logic and page objects and I'm also use techniques you mentioned in third paragraph :)

Answer (score 0):

use a generic method for all your operation which can repeat dudring all the tests:

```
public void click(WebElement webElement)
{
webElement.click();
}
```